# Neutral accent or a neutral accent (countable or not)

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

In the context of the sentence below, which should be applied so it's grammatical.

> The only thing that is good about our country (as a single noun) is our spoken English, we've got **neutral accent.**

Or

> The only thing that is good about our country (as a single noun) is our spoken English, we've got **a neutral accent.**

P.S.: should it be countable or uncountable?

Comment: Which country? Everybody has an accent.

Comment: I've edited it to be clear. My bad

Comment: about our country, not in our country. You need the article.

Comment: He still won't say what the country is.

Comment: @Lambie, thx, I've changed it.

Comment: @Micheal: this is just a sample sentence for learning English, not a FACT-finding measure. I think it doesn't matter to state a country, right? Anyway, my bad for the late reply.

Comment: I think he got stuck on the accent rather than the "a". :)

Comment: Everybody I have ever met who said "I speak English with no accent" or "I speak with a neutral accent" had a very strong identifiable accent.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider 'neutral accent' to be a generic feature of the way people speak English in your country, then it is an uncountable (mass) term in the same way that rhoticity or th-fronting are uncountable. On the other hand, if you are considering the accent as one among others, e.g. those found in other countries, you would use an indefinite article. Consider "large mass is a desirable quality in a gold bar to be given to me" and "that gold bar over there has a large mass".